# Adjusting for precision when casting a uint64_t to a double

Tags: c++, double, precision

I have a method that returns a string representation of time in the following format:  _HH:MM:SS.sss the method takes an uint64_t time in microseconds as an arg. I can divide the hours and minutes out easily enough, but when it comes to the seconds, I need to cast to a double so I can get the fraction of seconds as well.

sample code:

```
std::string getDurationTime(uint64_t time){

  std::string returnTime="";

   uint64_t tempTime = time;
   uint64_t hours = (tempTime / 3600000000);
   tempTime -= (hours * 3600000000);

   uint64_t minutes = (tempTime / 60000000);
   tempTime -= (minutes * 60000000);

   double seconds = (double(tempTime) / 1000000);

   stringstream timeOut;

   timeOut<<std::setw(2)<<std::setfill('0')<<hours<<":"<<std::setw(2)<<std::setfill('0')<<minutes<<":"<<std::fixed<<std::setw(6)<<std::setprecision(3)<<std::setfill('0')<<seconds;

  returnTime = "_" + timeOut.str();

  return returnTime;

}
```

So  a number like 103566 should return a value of _00:00:00:104, but instead it is returning _00:00:00:103. When I put a break point on seconds, the value is 0.103499999.  Is there a standard technique for adjusting for this precision? If I add .000001 to the resulting seconds will it fix the problem every time for that precision?

any advice appreciated.

Comment: First, there's no apparent reason to constrain this function to run only on processors that have an unsigned integral type with **exactly** 64 bits; use `uint_least64_t` instead of `uint64_t`. Second, It's not at all obvious that the code needs to convert to `double`. What problem is this conversion supposed to solve?

Comment: When doing time arithmetic in C++, I recommend you to take a look at the new [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) namespace in C++11.

Comment: @Pete Becker I don't understand what you mean"What problem is this conversion supposed to solve?". The cast is changing a .0035 to a .00349999 in a precision of 3 (ie its not rounding up because .00049999 < .0005)

Comment: I believe you've misrepresented the problem: http://ideone.com/b3B1cP `double(103566)/1000000` should be .103566, not .1035.

Comment: @Mark if the stringstream timeOut's<< std::fixed <<std::setprecision(3) then the double should be rounding up to .104. It wasn't because of the precision error from the cast to a double.

Comment: You start out with an integral number of microseconds. Why do you think you need to convert to double to get seconds? Just divide by 1000000 to get seconds, reduce the value just as you did for all the other values, and you've got the remaining microseconds.

Comment: @Miek, did you follow the link I gave? It shows a result of .104, just as expected. The code you show should work just fine, so I suspect your actual code has something else wrong with it that's hidden from us. Seeing an intermediate value of 0.103499999 is just plain incorrect.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the link Mark. I don't know whats up then. I'll have to dig around. Thats the behavior I am expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `seconds = round(seconds * 1000.0) / 1000.0;` to round your number to thousands of a second.

Comment: Yep. Thats looking like the solution. Thank You.